# Why this php interface code is work?

Tags: php

```
<?php
interface interfaceA{
    public function getA();
}

class classA implements interfaceA {
    public function getA()
    {
        echo 11;
    }

    public function getB(){
        echo 22;
    }

}

$classA = new classA();
functionA($classA);

function functionA(interfaceA $data){
    $data->getA();
    $data->getB();
}
```

Phpstorm error : Method 'getB' not found in interfaceA
but is very good work....

This Code Output : 1122

Comment: And why it should __not__ work?

Comment: It does not work in Java.
I want to know why it works in php.

Comment: [**It works in Java too**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9715574/2191572). You just have to make sure your IDE allows for it. A class can have methods which are not declared in the interface.

Comment: wow it is compiler setting problem? I learn good things.

Comment: @June_C, Java is a compiled strict-typed language, PHP is an interpreted loosely-typed language.   Pretty big differences.  Java's compiler will catch a lot of things that may cause run-time errors in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll work in this occurrence because you're passing in an object that does have a getB method.  However, it's not guaranteed to work because you didn't define getB on the interface.

Your input requirement only guarantees a getA method.  You defined your input as InterfaceA, not classA. Therefore, PhpStorm is telling you that your input requirements do not match your usage and that this usage may lead to run-time errors when you pass some other type of instance implementing InterfaceA.

Comment: What do you  mean?  PHP isn't compiled, where do you expect the error to exist?

Comment: I'm sorry, my English is not good.  I just want make error like phpstorm error message

Comment: I don't think you understand the difference between compiled and interpreted languages.  This will error at run-time if you pass an invalid implementation of InterfaceA.  There would be no other time for it to error.  PHP does not have a compiler like Java,  PHPStorm is giving you the hint instead.